# TinyMCE not working on boostrap modal data-dismiss and then reopen

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using boostrap 3 and tinymce 4. I am trying to put tinymce in a modal and it work fine, but when I use data-dismiss on the modal and then reopen it again tinymce does not show in the modal window. code as follows:

for tinymce

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#tinytext",
    plugins: "image code autolink link charmap insertdatetime table media textcolor emoticons",
    browser_spellcheck: true,
    //image_dimensions: false,

    toolbar: ["undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify ",
        " bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | forecolor backcolor | emoticons"]
});
```

for modal cancel

```
 $('#Modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

    $(this).removeData("bs.modal").find(".modal-content").empty();
});
```

I would like to be able to close the modal and reopen it again with tinymce still attach to #tinytext

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. You must remove the tinymce instance in the modal before you try and reload it again. on my modal when I call the 'hidden.bs.modal' I need to close any instance of tinymce that was used in the closing modal.

code:
   $('#Modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

```
tinymce.remove("#tinytext);
$(this).removeData("bs.modal").find(".modal-content").empty();
```

});

once you do that, when you reopen the modal, the tinymce instance will reinitialize with no problem.

Comment: tinymce.remove("#tinytext"); work for me, no need removeData(). Thanks.